# Limit Maximum Concurrent Session per user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session

Hello Team I am trying to set limit of concurrent sessions per user. I am trying to limit it using session management, but it is not working as expected. I have tried to set max sessions to 1, but i am able to have more than 1 active sessions.
Please find the configuration

http.csrf().disable()

```
            // take all the default security headers
            .headers()

            .contentTypeOptions().and()

            .xssProtection().and()

            .cacheControl().disable().addHeaderWriter(new StaticAndDynamicCacheControlHeaderWriter(cacheTimeDays))

            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().and()

            // add X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()

            // Un-authenticated calls
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api")
            .permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/api")
            .access("authenticated or hasIpAddress('localhost')").and()

            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler).and()

            // Login configuration - the default action here is POST.
            .formLogin().permitAll().loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_LOGOUT_URI).successHandler(authLoginSuccessHandler).failureHandler(authLoginFailureHandler)
            .and()

            // Logout configuration
            .logout().permitAll().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGIN_LOGOUT_URI, "DELETE")).logoutSuccessHandler(authLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()

            
            .addFilter(getJsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter())

            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and()

            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and()

            .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
```

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be more to your application besides the configuration, so if you have a small reproducible example that might help. But in a simple application, I noticed the session management does not completely work unless you register an `HttpSessionEventPublisher`. Add the following to your `@Configuration`:

```
        @Bean
        public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
        }
```

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#concurrent-sessions) for more information on concurrent sessions.

Comment: Can you post a small reproducible example that shows the issue? Also, may be unrelated but is there a reason you have multiple `.authorizeRequests()` sections in this config? I believe those won't play well together so I'm not sure if it's related to the problem you're facing.